# Telegram webhook on laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, bots, telegram

I'm trying to make a telegram bot on laravel.
I have [this](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) package in the project and everything is ok when I want to send a pm to a static chat_id to my own telegram account.

But when I want to send a message to bot in telegram and get a simple response, webhook url isn't calling by telegram!

a few hours ago I have recieved many webhook calls (about 3000) in my log but now it is not working again

for your information:
I have this except in my VerifyCsrfToken.php:

```
protected $except = [
  '/bot'
];
```

and this is my webhook url:
 https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/setwebhook?url=[URL]

and I have ssl certification on this url!

Comment: Is your webhook set?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi yes.. but I think I have repeated setting webhook on two different urls. Could this cause the problem?!

Comment: On webhookset you set a url for a bot's token, it always overries the prior one, so make sure again that your webhook is set correctlh

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I have tried and this is my response:
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}
but still is not working..

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
protected $except = [
    'bot*'
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris